# Automatic Cashflow Generation in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering if there is a formula to create a new cell and apply a formula as many time as the number entered into a specific cell. For example if I have a cell where I enter the duration of a property lease for example 10 years, is there a way to create a new column headed with the number of the year and with a cell below it with the starting rent escalated as many times as the number of years of the lease as entered elsewhere on the sheet?

I need to create a cashflow with as many cells as the number of years entered in the Lease duration cell. So for example if I enter 10 into the "Lease duration cell", I need excel to automatically create 10 columns with the starting rent in column 1 and then the escalated rent for each subsequent year for the remaining 9 years.

[image: Can the Highlighted parts of this spreadsheet be automated with a formula?]

Id like to know if there is a way to automate using a formula the yellow highlighted parts of this spreadsheet? If I enter "10" in the lease duration cell, is there a way for excel to automatically create the cashflow for 10 years escalating the rent per the % entered in the "escalation" cell?

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

With Office 365 Excel we can use VSTACK, HSTACK, SEQUENCE and some math to make it dynamic:

```
=VSTACK(SEQUENCE(,B3+1,0),HSTACK(-B4,B5*(1+B2)^(SEQUENCE(,B3,0))))
```

SEQUENCE is what makes the arrays dynamic, VSTACK and HSTACK just stacks the data correctly

[image]